# Marathi localization does not activate at start-up for libre office

Tags: internationalization, localization

When I start ubuntu, I see a list of all languages. I choose Marathi and expect to see marathi interface for libre office and other applications. The UI is still english.

I have added a bug here...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1469712

I will like to know what else can I do to fix this.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Okay, close vote retracted based on your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marathi should work in LibreOffice. Possibly, based on your description, you haven't installed the required language support packages. The easiest way to check it out is to open *System Settings -> Language Support*. Then, if there are missing language support packages, you'll be prompted to install them. Just accept that.

In particular I think it's the **libreoffice-l10n-mr** package which needs to be installed.

Comment: Thanks. Is there similar package for firefox?

Comment: @shantanuo: Yes, firefox-locale-mr. It should have been installed if you did as I suggested above.