# Czech Localization for LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, snap, internationalization

I am running on Ubuntu 20 04. I have LibreOffice 6.4.4.2 installed and trying to switch its user interface to Czech language.

I have installed the package `libreoffice-l10n-cs` and restarted LibreOffice.

When I click on Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Languages, "User Interface" is set to "Default - English (USA)". When I expand the select, "Czech" is not listed in the options.

There are other questions about language support in LibreOffice on Ask Ubuntu, like

[how to change LibreOffice UI's language?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862054/how-to-change-libreoffice-uis-language)

[Marathi localization does not activate at start-up for libre office](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668122/marathi-localization-does-not-activate-at-start-up-for-libre-office)

but they did not help me to switch Libre Office to Czech.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The commands suggested by N0rbert produce the following output:

```
$ which lowriter

$ dpkg -l | grep libreoffice

ii  libreoffice-common                         1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- arch-independent files
ii  libreoffice-core                           1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        office productivity suite -- arch-dependent files
ii  libreoffice-help-common                    1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- common files for LibreOffice help
ii  libreoffice-help-cs                        1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- Czech help
ii  libreoffice-help-en-gb                     1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- English_british help
ii  libreoffice-help-en-us                     1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- English_american help
ii  libreoffice-l10n-cs                        1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- Czech language package
ii  libreoffice-l10n-en-gb                     1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- English_british language package
ii  libreoffice-l10n-en-za                     1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- English_southafrican language package
ii  libreoffice-l10n-sk                        1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- Slovak language package
ii  libreoffice-style-colibre                  1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- colibre symbol style
ii  libreoffice-style-tango                    1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          office productivity suite -- Tango symbol style

$ snap list | grep -i libreoffice

libreoffice        6.4.4.2                     180   latest/stable    canonical*  -
```

The command flatpack is not intalled.

Comment: How did you installed libreoffice? Please add output of `which lowriter`, `dpkg -l | grep -i libreoffice`, `snap list | grep -i libreoffice`, `flatpak list | grep -i libreoffice` to the question.

Comment: I installed minimal installation of Ubuntu, i.e. without LibreOffice. Then I installed LibreOffice from "Ubuntu Software" application and finally added cs package using apt: sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-cs In fact, I supposed that Ubuntu Software is just user interface that uses apt internally. ...and maybe this is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you have to remove Snap version of libreoffice with

```
snap remove libreoffice
```

then install LibreOffice from deb-packages with

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

and then installing full set of localization with

```
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support -l cs)
```

should help.

Comment: I have tried just the command: check-language-support -l cs And its output is empty.

Comment: See updated answer, start with removing Snap'ed version of LibreOffice with `snap remove libreoffice` and then install deb-package with `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`. Then localization should become available.

Comment: Nice answer, @N0rbert. Do you know if that snap bug has been reported?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I do not know. But I suspect that other snap'ed apps with extensions/plugins/addons may be affected with same nature.

Comment: @N0rbert: I would be surprised if this kind of issue is present for e.g. the FF or Chromium snap. But there is unfortunately a general tendency to publish snaps in an experimental stage.